# (XCode 7.1.1) How to center an ImageView?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.1.1

I am having a difficult time understanding the new way of designing XIB layout (i.e. constraints).

I have seen some tutorials and lessons, yet I'm not sure why I'm not understanding any of it.

Here is my simple scenario that I want to achieve:
a) I was a custom 'splash' screen that simply displays an ImageView that is vertically & horizontally centered (and retain aspect ratio).
b) When I can achieve and understand (a), I would also like to add a label (or some other simple UI element) that also displays nicely across various screen sizes.

Question 1:
What is the starting point to learning constraints, if indeed constraints is what I need to understand here.

Question 2:
What references/tutorials/examples has worked well for you in understanding the new way of layout design?

Comment: Documentations available in XCode are sufficient, but need a patient and careful reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) is, to my knowledge, the most recent Apple guide on learning Auto Layout. There's also [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) tutorial from [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com) updated for iOS 9. There's no reason you shouldn't be able to accomplish what you're asking after reading through either or both of these.